# Notification LED flashing in windows-phone-8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working in Phone 8 development,
I have been given a use case, where i need to handle Notification LED depending on different kinds of Notification, for example, for "Urgent message" i am supposed to Blink Notification LED very fast or blink an Red LED, For "Medium Message" Blink Notification Led at a medium Pace, or blink Amber LED, For "Low Message", Have to Blink Notification LED at a Lower Pace or Blink Green LED,

If Flashing of LED is Not Possible, is there a way where i can flash at least the Window Button which is at the Bottom Center of the Device.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no notification LED on any Windows Phone, be it a red or a green LED, so what you're asking for is impossible.

As for blinking the Windows button, that's a nice idea but there's unfortunately no API for that, so it's also a dead end.